# SELECT based on the result of another SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to run another SELECT based on the result of the first SELECT?

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1
```

If the result is 0, I want to display the result of:

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM table2
```

If the result of the first SELECT is NOT 0, display the result of the first query and IGNORE the second.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: All the searches gave a solution of using inner select, which is not relevant. These are unrelated queries

Comment: what was your google search string?

Comment: stuff like "another select based on select result". different variations of that

Comment: and i do know that in order to combine queries i need to have same amount of columns of the same type, and i know i don't have it here. this is why i'm asking if there is another way. fyi mr. @FreshPrinceOfSO

Comment: Try "sql server set variable with select" and "sql server set if else example".  You'll need them both.  Or you can cheat and read Phil's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly run a second select based on the results of the first:

You could do this:

```
declare @count integer = (select count(*) from table1)

if @count = 0
    select ... from table1
else
    select ... from table2
```

Comment: just wondering... if the "select count(*) from table1" will be a super long query, and will be written again under "else", it will do the whole thing twice. is it possible to insert the result of @count under "else" without copy-paste?

Comment: Much faster - particularly against a large table - to say `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.table1)` instead of getting the count, which requires a full scan of the narrowest non-filtered index. Since in this case you don't care about the count, you can use `EXISTS` to short circuit when a single row is found.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the first query is the count, so you can use the variable to avoid re-running the query.

```
DECLARE @count int = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS )

IF @count > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @count AS total
END
```

Comment: Okay, I'm new here. Sorry I didn't see how to format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't need a variable for your problem

```
if EXISTS (select * from table1)
    select A, B, C from table2
```